# Client-side JS & Server-side C# Communication

Tags: javascript, c#, http

I've got a web application that's running Js on client side and c# on server side - What would be the best way for them to communicate over the internet and how would I pull that off - would really appreciate some resources, I've been looking around for a bit now and couldn't find anything.

There wont only be credentials from forms that will be passed through, there will be other data coming from the server time to time as well

Comment: Web sockets. For ASP.NET the best is SignalR - a library that removes the boilerplatey details

Comment: [Raw WebSockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), [Writing a WebSocket server in C#](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server), [SignalR docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer is [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). I believe that there is good support for this in c#, and I know for myself that it's pretty easy to set up in JavaScript. You can use "ws" or a secure connection with "wss".

The one thing I would warn you about is with "credentials" and sensitive information in JavaScript. On the client side, you basically have no control over preventing sensitive information from leaking. Web pages can be altered and inspected by the client. So be careful about what your server sends to your client.